# PNG with transparent background = thumbnail with black backgroud

Tags: php, png, transparency

Can you support me?
I have the following script in order to create a thumbnail, works fine!
BUT, when I upload a PNG file with transparent background, for some reason the background change to black.

```
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
```

If the background of the PNG it's transparent, I need the thumbnail transparent also, can you please support me?
 Any help will be GREAT!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your code is supposed to work, but it looks like your thumbnails are all JPEGs? JPEG doesn't support transparency at all, so the areas that are transparent in the source image must be filled with some colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
$tci = imagecreate($w, $h);
```

Instead:

```
$tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
```

My issue is now solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
```

by this:

```
imagegif($tci, $newcopy, 80);
```

Or the equivalent function depending on the image format:

[Imagepng](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagepng.php)

[Imagegif](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagegif.php)

[Imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagejpeg.php)

[Imagebmp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagewbmp.php)

Comment: I've tried, but no change :( I will try to find another script... Thanks for your help